# PHP - get next weekday but skip Monday between 13:00 Fri and 24:00 Sun

Tags: php, date

The following displays the next working day from today, skipping bank holidays declared in an array.

```
function get_next_workday() { 
  $bankhols = array(
    '25-Dec-2018',
    '26-Dec-2018',
  ); 
  $nextdays = array(strtotime('+1 day'), strtotime('+2 days'), strtotime('+3 days'), strtotime('+4 days'), strtotime('+5 days')); 
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($nextdays); $i++) { 
    $daynum = (int) date('w', $nextdays[$i]); 
    $daytext = date('d-M-Y', $nextdays[$i]); 
    if (($daynum > 0) && ($daynum < 6) && (!in_array($daytext, $bankhols))) { 
      return $nextdays[$i]; 
    } 
  }
}

echo date('l, jS F', get_next_workday());
```

I am trying to get the delivery day for an eccommerce site that has a next day cut off time of 1pm. Can anyone help me modify this to skip to the following working day if after the cutoff time?

Comment: when you echo the date put a if to check if it is valid in your rules and if not rerun the function using the invalid date as input so you will get a new date in the future that is valid

Comment: Why does this have 4 votes to close as 'too broad'? I don't see anything wrong with the question

Comment: I don't understand why this is too broad - can you explain please so that I don't do it again?

Comment: I have the answer to my own question and I would like to post it for other people looking for similar help. I have modified the text so hopefully it's not "too broad". Can we review and re-open this question so that I can answer it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a "start" date to increment from, so rather than working out a delivery date, work out the current date, see where it fits into your rules, then increment the "start" date until it passes your rules.

Then you can figure out your delivery date:

```
function get_next_workday() {
  $bankhols = array('25-Dec-2018', '26-Dec-2018');
  $increment_days = 5;

  $dayincrease  = 1; // Used if today happens to fall on a weekend / fri > 1pm
  $start_date   = date('d-M-Y', strtotime('now')); // Assume the "start" date is now
  $nownum       = (int)date('w', strtotime('now'));

  // Continue to increment the "start" date if it's a Fri > 1pm, Sat, or Sun
  while ( in_array($nownum, array(6,0)) OR ($nownum===5 AND (int)date('H')>13) ) {
    $newdate      = strtotime('+'.$dayincrease.' day');
    $nownum       = date('w', $newdate);
    $start_date   = date('d-M-Y', $newdate);
    $dayincrease++;
  }

  // Now we have a "start" date to work from
  // (either now, or, the following monday),
  // we can now find the delivery dates

  for ($i=1; $i<=$increment_days; $i++) {
    // Increment the Delivery Date another day (from our "start" date)
    $delivery   = strtotime($start_date.'+'.$i.' day');
    // As long as it's a Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, and Not Bank Holidays, it's a delivery date!
    if (in_array((int)date('w', $delivery), array(1,2,3,4,5)) AND !in_array(date('d-M-Y', $delivery), $bankhols)) return $delivery;
  }
}

echo date('l, jS F', get_next_workday());
```

The first "while" loop implements your after Friday 1pm before Sunday midnight check, if the current time IS within that window, it keeps incrementing a day until if falls out the window.

Then the delivery date can be found using that start date.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've modified the while loop to have a cut off time of 1pm on all workdays:
`while ( 
          in_array($nownum, array(6,0)) 
          OR ($nownum===1 AND (int)date('H')>13) 
          OR ($nownum===2 AND (int)date('H')>13) 
          OR ($nownum===3 AND (int)date('H')>13) 
          OR ($nownum===4 AND (int)date('H')>13) 
          OR ($nownum===5 AND (int)date('H')>13) 
        ) {`
Is there a cleaner way to write this?